# Minimum bytes required to represent a signed hexadecimal value

Tags: perl, hex, pack

Can anyone tell me is there any function in Perl which converts signed decimal to Hex with minimum number of bytes.

ex: -555(dec) => FFFFFDD5(hex) [ converted using $Hex = sprintf( "%X", -555 )]

I want the result to be FDD5 instead of FFFFFDD5.

2 bytes are enough to represent -555.But i am getting 4 bytes conversion.

Please help!

Comment: I am sure it is an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: If you convert it back, how do you know that `FDD5` is `-555` instead of `64981`?

Comment: I completely agree with the previous commenters. [Just enough rope](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/105551): `perl -le 'print unpack("H*",pack("s>",-555))'` prints `fdd5` - try it also with the [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) patterns `"c"`, `"l>"`, and `"q>"`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your approach.

1. It's unparsable.

   For example, even if you only know you have two numbers,
   Bytes 12 34 56 78<sub>16</sub> could refer to 12<sub>16</sub> and 345678<sub>16</sub>.
   Bytes 12 34 56 78<sub>16</sub> could refer to 1234<sub>16</sub> and 5678<sub>16</sub>.
   Bytes 12 34 56 78<sub>16</sub> could refer to 123456<sub>16</sub> and 78<sub>16</sub>.

   You could use some external means of identifying the length of the encoded number, but that would nullify some or all of the savings.
2. It's ambiguous.

   For example,
   Bytes FD D5<sub>16</sub> could refer to 64981<sub>10</sub> (Bytes 00 00 FD D5<sub>16</sub> as an int32).
   Bytes FD D5<sub>16</sub> could refer to -555<sub>10</sub> (Bytes FF FF FD D5<sub>16</sub> as an int32).

One solution is to use a length prefix (like UTF-8).

```
-2^13..2^13-1  2 bytes  00xx xxxx  xxxx xxxx
-2^21..2^21-1  3 bytes  01xx xxxx  xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxx
-2^29..2^29-1  4 bytes  10xx xxxx  xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxx
-2^31..2^31-1  5 bytes  1100 0000  xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxx
```

The optimal scheme will depend on the distribution of your numbers.

---

The packing/encoding function for the above scheme could be written as follows:

```
sub pack_vint32 {
   my $n = shift;
   my $nn = $n >= 0 ? $n : ~$n;
   return substr(pack('L>', ($n & 0x3FFF    ) | 0x0000    ), -2) if !($nn & ~0x1FFF);
   return substr(pack('L>', ($n & 0x3FFFFF  ) | 0x400000  ), -3) if !($nn & ~0x1FFFFF);
   return substr(pack('L>', ($n & 0x3FFFFFFF) | 0x80000000), -4) if !($nn & ~0x1FFFFFFF);
   return "\xC0".pack('L>', $n);
}
```

And the unpacking/decoding function for the above scheme could be written as follows:

```
sub unpack_vint32 {
   for (shift) {
      if (/^[\x00-\x3F]/) {
         return if length() < 2;
         my $n = unpack('L>', "\x00\x00".substr($_, 0, 2, '')) & 0x3FFF;
         $n -= 0x4000 if $n & 0x2000;
         return $n;
      }
      elsif (/^[\x40-\x7F]/) {
         return if length() < 3;
         my $n = unpack('L>', "\x00".substr($_, 0, 3, '')) & 0x3FFFFF;
         $n -= 0x400000 if $n & 0x200000;
         return $n;
      }
      elsif (/^[\x80-\xBF]/) {
         return if length() < 4;
         my $n = unpack('L>', substr($_, 0, 4, '')) & 0x3FFFFFFF;
         $n -= 0x40000000 if $n & 0x20000000;
         return $n;
      }
      elsif (/^\xC0/) {
         return if length() < 5;
         return unpack('xl>', substr($_, 0, 5, ''));
      }
      elsif (length() == 0) {
         return;
      }
   }

   croak("Bad data");
}
```

Test:

```
my $s =
   join '',
      map { pack_vint32($_) }
         map { $_, -$_ }
            130, 555, 0x12, 0x345678, 0x12345678;

say length($s);
say sprintf("%v02X", $s);

while ( my ($n) = unpack_vint32($s) ) {
   say $n;
}

croak("Bad data") if length($s);
```

Output:

```
28
00.82.3F.7E.02.2B.3D.D5.00.12.3F.EE.80.34.56.78.BF.CB.A9.88.92.34.56.78.AD.CB.A9.88
----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
130     |     |     |     |     |        |           |           |           |
-130 ---+     |     |     |     |        |           |           |           |
555 ----------+     |     |     |        |           |           |           |
-555 ---------------+     |     |        |           |           |           |
18 -----------------------+     |        |           |           |           |
-18 ----------------------------+        |           |           |           |
3430008 ---------------------------------+           |           |           |
-3430008 --------------------------------------------+           |           |
305419896 -------------------------------------------------------+           |
-305419896 ------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the question wants the string (ASCII) representation in hexadecimal that takes the minimum number of bytes in two's complement. I agree with comments and another answer regarding this being ambiguous, but it may be fine for "human" consumption. In this case:

```
sub min_bytes {
  my $n = shift;

  my $s = 256; # Fits in one byte
  my $i = 1;   # Bytes counter
  while( 1 ) {
    if( $n < 0 && -$n <= $s / 2 ) {
      return $i;
    }
    elsif( $n >= 0 && $n < ($s / 2) - 1 ) {
      return $i;
    }
    $s *= 256;
    $i++;
  }
}

sub to_hex {
  my $n = shift;

  my $l = min_bytes($n);
  my $h = $n > 0 ? $n : (256 ** $l) + $n;

  my $s = '';
  for( my $i = 0; $i < $l; $i++ ) {
    $s = unpack('H2', pack('C', $n % 256)) . $s;
    $n = $n >> 8;
  }

  return $s;
}

# Let's try a few numbers
my @numbers = (-10, -555, -100000, -100000000, -10000000000, -10000000000000);

for my $n (@numbers) {
  my $l = min_bytes($n);
  my $h = to_hex($n);
  print $n, " takes ", $l, " byte(s) and looks like ", uc $h, "\n";
}
```

I have tried not to use anything complicated. The bit `unpack('H2', pack('C', $n % 256))` converts a single byte decimal number into hex.

This prints:

```
-10 takes 1 byte(s) and looks like F6
-555 takes 2 byte(s) and looks like FDD5
-100000 takes 3 byte(s) and looks like FE7960
-100000000 takes 4 byte(s) and looks like FA0A1F00
-10000000000 takes 5 byte(s) and looks like FDABF41C00
-10000000000000 takes 6 byte(s) and looks like F6E7B18D6000
```

The code uses Perl arithmetic, which may give wrong results for bigger numbers than the internal representation's precision.

Comment: @ikegami, I love your answer, but I think we are reading the question differently. The way I understand it, the OP wants the hex representation of a number using the minimum number of bytes. For `-555` wants `FDD5` and not `FFFFFDD5`. That´s represented with two bytes, which in hex is four bytes as you point out. Of course, I may be wrong...

Comment: Your solution converts `-555` into 4 bytes, but I believe the wants it to be converted into 2 bytes.

Comment: Your program lies about the sizes. For example, `-555` takes four bytes in your program, but the program claims it only takes two. To get the correct size, use `length($s)`. (This was fixed, but the fix got reverted???)

Comment: The size returned is the minimum number of bytes required to store the number in binary using two's complement. That is used to produce the string with the same number represented in hexadecimal.

Comment: Re "*The size returned is the minimum number of bytes required to store the number in binary using two's complement.*", I know, and that doesn't contradict anything I said. Perhaps you should change the output to "-10 would take 1 byte(s) as a two's-completement number"? But it's surely best to report what the program actually does instead of what it could do.